# Firebase Database Trigger returning null

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I created a Firebase Cloud function for database trigger and managed to deploy it successfully but the function could not retrieve data.

```
exports.newRide = functions.database.ref('/ride/{userid}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log("THIS IS SNAPSHOT");
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      console.log("THIS IS userid");
      myUID = context.params.userid;
      console.log({[myUID] : 1});
      console.log("This is[myUID]")
      console.log([myUID]);
      console.log("This is the wildcardname")
      wildCardValue = context.params.wildCardName
      console.log(wildCardValue);
      return snapshot.val();
);
```

Which returns `null` or `undefined` in the console log.

```
2020-08-05 16:23:36.276 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 null
2020-08-05 16:23:36.276 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 THIS IS userid
2020-08-05 16:23:36.276 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 null
2020-08-05 16:23:36.276 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 { '{userid}': 1 }
2020-08-05 16:23:36.276 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 THIS IS SNAPSHOT parent
2020-08-05 16:23:36.276 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 This is[myUID]
2020-08-05 16:23:36.276 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 [ '{userid}' ]
2020-08-05 16:23:36.276 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 This is the wildcardname
2020-08-05 16:23:36.280 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 Reference {
2020-08-05 16:23:36.280 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 repo:
2020-08-05 16:23:36.280 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 Repo {
2020-08-05 16:23:36.280 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 repoInfo_:
2020-08-05 16:23:36.280 HKTnewRidedxxxxea8zyc3 RepoInfo {
...
```

This is the database structure which I used in the cloud function test.

```
{
    "ride": {
        "uid123": {
            "destination": "ChIJJz7FNzUPER8j__MWKHY",
            "distance": "21.1 km",
            "duration": "18 mins",
            "expoPushToken": "ExponentPushToken[Y-YRJKEQU-lngkLAi]",
            "latitude": 1.3291467,
            "longitude": 103.776495,
            "price": 16
        }
    }
}
```

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.5.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you pls share the content of your `package.json` file?

Comment: Hi Renaud, I just added

Comment: From your code, your Cloud Function should correctly log `snapshot.val()`and `context.params.userid`. Can you include a screenshot of the console you are looking at? Also, note this doc [item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) on CF Life Cycle, it's really key.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Here is the [link to the console.log photo on imgur.](https://imgur.com/a/K1VhaVJ) Sorry, as a new account, I could not post images without 10 reputations. I added a return value. Meanwhile, I'll just recreate the cloud function and see how it goes. Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: Thanks for all the files added. Actually I don't think I can help you anymore at this stage, as I said, it should work. Try creating a new Firebase project from scratch.

Comment: Are you using onCreate method because you are adding new data to the Realtime Database? Check this [tutorial where it explains the difference between onWrite() and onCreate method](https://fullstackgcp.com/understanding-firebase-cloud-functions-and-triggers-cloud-high-voltage-cjyju2w9x000heds15ex7b4bq). Could you please try to use onWrite data if your data is previously created?